# How to resize webpage according to screen size?

Tags: css

Here is the CSS code for my webpage, I want to resize this page according to screen size and resolution.
Different div classes are made to style the div containers.
column1 is fixed div at left and column2 is scrollable div which contain further divs that needs to be resized according to the screen size.

```
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 22%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20pt;
  color: #e6b122;
  position: fixed;
}

.photo {
    margin: auto;
    height: 90px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column2 {
  float: right;
  width: 78%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
}

.photo img {
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.image {
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image img {
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Skill {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20pt;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 330px;
  border: 4px solid #F281F0;
  border-radius: 35px;
}

h4 {
    color: #C39D19;
}

p {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: cursive;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: 14px;
}

a:hover {
    color: #cc00cc
}

/* Container around content */
.container {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #CEF334;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

/* The circles on the timeline */
.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: -17px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #FF9F55;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Place the container to the left */
.left {
  left: 0;
}

/* Place the container to the right */
.right {
  left: 50%;
}

/* Add arrows to the left container (pointing right) */
.left::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
}

/* Add arrows to the right container (pointing left) */
.right::before {
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 30px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
}

/* Fix the circle for containers on the right side */
.right::after {
  left: -18px;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

/* Media queries - Responsive timeline on screens less than 600px wide */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  }
  
/* Arrows*/
.container::before {
  left: 60px;
  border: medium solid white;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
  }

/*For circles*/
.left::after, .right::after {
    left: 16px;
  }
 /* Left containers position */ 
.right {
    left: 0%;
}

</style>
```

Comment: You have to use media queries to do this. You can find a lot of tutorials online

Answer (score 2):

I learned how to layout my webpage by understanding the following CSS Layout tools.

- Flexbox
- CSS Grid
- Media Queries

You use Flexbox and CSS Grid to layout your content, while Media Queries can help your website be responsive to different media(Phone, Tablets, Desktop etc...) sizes.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are two good solutions for your issue:

1. Use the Media Queries, and set the proper config for your content depends on the viewport of the browser. I can see in the code, that you already use it, so you know how to deal with it.
2. the second option is to use a flexbox display, which will adjust content size depend on the page width. Here you have probably the best explanation on how to use flexbox:
   https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/